# Show that $\bf (a^\top Q b)^2 \le a^\top Q a \ b^\top Q b$!

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

where $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a positive definite matrix and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

The actual problem is, that $\bf ||x||_Q = \sqrt{x^\top Qx}$ should be a norm, but this is as far as I've gotten trying to show that $\bf||a+b||_Q \le ||a||_Q + ||b||_Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor $Q = M^{\mathsf T}M$ for some matrix $M$; let $\mathbf x = M\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf y = M \mathbf b$.

(One of the characterizations of positive semidefinite matrices is that they have such a characterization. If you haven't seen it, it follows from the existence of an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors. This gives us a factorization $Q = P^{-1}D P = P^{\mathsf T} D P$, and then we can let $M = D^{\frac12} P$.)

Then your statement becomes $(\mathbf x^{\mathsf T}\mathbf y)^2 \le \mathbf x^{\mathsf T}\mathbf x \mathbf y^{\mathsf T}\mathbf y$, which is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Also, $\|\mathbf a\|_Q, \|\mathbf b\|_Q, \|\mathbf a + \mathbf b\|_Q$ become $\|\mathbf x\|, \|\mathbf y\|, \|\mathbf x+\mathbf y\|$, so the inequality you want to show turns into the triangle inequality for the standard norm.